number of edges bounding cells
The following is a problem from Matousek's discrete geometry book (4.3.3).
problem: Let $K ( n, m)$ denote the maximum total number of edges of $m$ distinct cells in an arrangement of $n$ lines in the plane. Prove $K(n, m) =
O(n^{\frac{2}{3}}m^{\frac{2}{3}} + n + m)$ (it may be convenient to classify edges into top and bottom ones and bound each
type separately).
Hint/solution: Choose a point set $P$, one point in each of the $m$ cells. From each top edge, cut off a little segment $ab$ and replace it by the segments $ap$ and $pb$,
where $p\in P$ lies below the edge. Each line is replaced by a polygonal curve.
Consider a graph drawing with $P$ as the vertices and the polygonal curves
defining edges.
Another solution appears in wikipedia
What I need is just help to understand one of the solutions. If someone can elaborate on the proof I would very much appriciate it. In particular a drawing would be best to help me validate I understand the problem and the constructions.
